Sort Tuple by first element in A1 B1 C1 order
I have zip two lists which I'm trying to sort the tuple by A1 B1 C1
l1 = ['F2', 'G2', 'B2', 'H2', 'A3', 'E3', 'G3', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'D2', 'C3', 'A1']
l2 = [40, 40, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 120, 120, 120, 120, 120, 90]

Code
l1, l2 = [list(i) for i in zip(*sorted(zip(l1, l2), key=lambda x: list(map(int,x[0][1:]))))]

print (l1)
print (l2)

Current output:
['C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'A1', 'F2', 'G2', 'B2', 'H2', 'D2', 'A3', 'E3', 'G3', 'C3']
[120, 120, 120, 90, 40, 40, 90, 90, 120, 90, 90, 90, 120]

The expected result should instead be:
l1 = ['A1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'B2', 'D2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'A3', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3']

How do I get the expected result instead of what I currently get?

In your own words, what are the rules for sorting? The code suggest you want to sort just by the numbers of the items in l1. The desired output suggest you want to sort by the items in l1, first by the trailing number then by the letter. How should your code treat numbers with more than one digit? Does 'A1' come before or after A10?

I am not really sure what your code is trying to do.  I can get your desired result as follows:
l1 = list(sorted(l1, key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])))
print(l1)

Output:
['A1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'B2', 'D2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'A3', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3']

Note: This solution only works if the items in l1 are two characters in length ('A10' would not be sorted properly).
You don't show l2 in your desired result.
Update
If you want to sort both lists at the same time, you can combine them as follows:
combined = zip(l1, l2)
combined = list(sorted(combined, key=lambda item: (item[0][1], item[0][0])))
print(combined)

Output:
[('A1', 90), ('C1', 120), ('D1', 120), ('E1', 120), ('B2', 90), ('D2', 120), ('F2', 40), ('G2', 40), ('H2', 90), ('A3', 90), ('C3', 120), ('E3', 90), ('G3', 90)]

To unzip the combined result use these statements:
l1_sorted = [item[0] for item in combined]
l2_sorted = [item[1] for item in combined]

You can also use the zip function for unzipping as explained here.

Bill List l1 is tied to list l2. As they are zipped a tuple is created [("C1", 120), ("D1", 120), etc.]

Ah I see.  I have added an update to show how to sort the combined list of tuples.

The result should be as follows l1 = ['A1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1', 'B2', 'D2', 'F2', 'G2', 'H2', 'A3', 'C3', 'E3', 'G3'] l2 = [90, 120, 120, 120, 90, 90, 40, 40, 90, 90, 120, 90, 90]

Thanks Bill! This is Perfect!

Next time, put the complete desired output in the question so it is clearer what you want.

How would you sort A10? i.e. ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2',, ......'A9', 'B9', 'C9', 'A10', 'B10', 'C10'?

That is not difficult to do. I would first split each string into two parts, the alphabetic part (string) and the numeric part (integer). Then you could pass this list of tuples to the same sorting algorithm used here.
